# How do you add a "Resend code" for Azure AD B2C phone sign-in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using the following passwordless policy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication

As per the screenshots in that post, the sign-up has a "Send new code" button but the sign-in does not.

Is this by design or is there a way to add the "Send new code" button to the sign-in flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for reaching out. The reason the sign in page has no `Send new code`, is because it moves to a subsequent page to verify the code. If the code verification is on the same page, as implemented in the sign up technical profile, then we would have `Send new code` button visible on the SignIn Page.

Comment: Thanks @SouravMishra-MSFT Just to clarify: Are you saying that if you make the sign-in look like the sign-up (all on same page) it will work?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Once you mimic the SignUp Technical Profile for SignIn, you should see the Send New Code option on SignIn too.